# How to mock java methods of superclass using powermock or any mock tool?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

Super class

```
public class BasicDao {
    public Object createQuery() {
        return new Object();
    }
}
```

Implementation

```
public class MyDAO implements BasicDao {
    public Object getMyData() {
        Object obj = createQuery();
        // more code...
        return ...;
    }
}
```

I need to test `getMyData()` method and I want to mock/suppress `createQuery()` method cos it will fail on test env.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do tests this way. This is called partial mocking and this is wrong, it means that the code that have been written is not using good **Object Oriented** design. One should favor [**Composition OVER Inheritance**](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples4.html).

Nevertheless DAO are object that represents the boundary of your system, i.e.

- one side is **Object Oriented**
- one side is **Relational**

In this case you should write integration tests,

- insert data in a DB, actual instance or in-memory instance ([h2](http://h2database.com), [hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org), ...)
- prepare your data, there's plenty possibilities here ([DbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net), [DbSetup](http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/), ...)
- configure and run your DAO tests on this database

It may require more setup and more time to run but it is better in the long run.

- more robust mapping testing
- easier to change the technical implementation, without changing tests
- run against a database, you can detect configuration issues/challenges sooner, and make sure they don't break 3 years later

---

Also answer of @user3386493 is technically correct but I'd suggest to use this kind of stubbing with spies (otherwise actual method code is executed) :

```
MyDAO daoSpy = Mockito.spy(new MyDAO());
doReturn(new Object()).when(daoSpy).createQuery();
```

Comment: Totally agree with it, managed to get the mock work here. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using Mockito.

```
@Test
public void testGetMyData() {
        MyDAO dao = new MyDAO();
        MyDAO daoSpy = Mockito.spy(dao);
        Mockito.when(daoSpy.createQuery()).thenReturn(new Object());
    }
```